# Using callbacks to insert into a table when a column in another table is modified

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a USERS table which stores the number of times a user has logged in as well as the IP they used and the timestamp (from devise). I want to keep track of the sign_in_count and whenever it increases, I want to create a new entry in another table that has the user id, their ip, and the timestamp. I have looked into the ActiveModel:Dirty module (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) but am not sure how to  implement it.

Comment: I'd recommend just using devise's built in `trackable` functionality...but if you want to store the data in a table other than `users` then you will need to override Devise's  `SessionsController#create` action...which there are many examples of

Answer (score 0):

Devise has a [built in trackable module](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:trackable-to-Users):

> Track information about your user sign in. It tracks the following
>   columns:
>
> - sign_in_count - Increased every time a sign in is made (by form, openid, oauth)
> - current_sign_in_at - A timestamp updated when the user signs in
> - last_sign_in_at - Holds the timestamp of the previous sign in
> - current_sign_in_ip - The remote ip updated when the user sign in
> - last_sign_in_ip - Holds the remote ip of the previous sign in

This is definately the easiest and best solution if it fits you use case. If you need a one to many assocation that keeps track of all the users sign ins you want to customize the controller - not create a model callback. (hint: [model callbacks are a code smell](https://medium.com/planet-arkency/the-biggest-rails-code-smell-you-should-avoid-to-keep-your-app-healthy-a61fd75ab2d3)).

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :sign_ins
end
```

```
class SignIn < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      user.sign_ins.create(
        ip_address: request.remote_ip
      )
    end
  end
end
```

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :user, controllers: { sessions: 'my_sessions' }
```

This will actually satisify all your requirements:

- sign_in_count is the count of rows on the join table.
- the latest sign is the `created_at` column of the latest row per user id.
- it stores the request ip.

You could actually combine it with trackable if you needed for some reason to store every sign in ip together but still have the latest sign in data on the users table for easy access.

Comment: Another way to do this is the same way as trackable - use the `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` hook in an initializer to setup your custom logic. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/715192a7709a4c02127afb067e66230061b82cf2/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb

Comment: This may work but I am not sure why you would override the devise controller in order to achieve a relatively simple model level task. Using a callback would allow you to keep your controllers skinny and far less code. And model callbacks being a "code smell" should not be used as a governing principle but case by case basis.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you have got the right idea to use a callback, this is how it could be implemented.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  after_save :track_sign_in_count



  private

  def track_sign_in_count
    if sign_in_count_changed?
      OtherTable.create!()
    end
  end

end
```

I am using an `after_save` callback which will be triggered every time the user record is updated or created. However, we have used a built in method `sign_in_count_changed?` so it will only create a new record in `OtherTable` if the `sign_in_count` has actually changed.

Inside the callback you can use `self` to get the model that is being updated or created, so you can get other attributed from it such as timestamps or whatever you need.

Note: if the `sign_in_count` does not change when the initial user record is created you can change the callback to `after_update` so it only runs when the user record is updated and not created.

Comment: The devise sessions controller does not modify the record so this code will do didly squat except on registrations#update where you don't want it to fire. Don't use a model callback for exactly this reason.

Comment: @max I am not sure what you mean the OP said "I want to keep track of the sign_in_count and whenever it increases" - I am working on a rails project now and have just tested my solution and this code will fire every time a user logs-in and the `sign_in_count` increases on the model! - I am using a callback in the model because `sign_in_count` is a simple attribute on the user model - I do not touch the controller or have to override it

Comment: That may be true but it will also fire every time the user updates their registration. - fail

Comment: agreed and that can be an issue with using callbacks hence the initial check `if sign_in_count_changed?`. I still personally prefer this way because it doesn't require creating a new controller and route and the use case is not taxing on performance.